# Write µ to CSV file using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, utf-8, character-encoding, c#-2.0

I am writing into CSV file using the following code

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
context.Response.Clear();                     
context.Response.Write("µm");                   
context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=micron.csv");
context.Response.End();
```

but in the UI it is getting displayed as `Âµm` instead of `µm`. Please I need a little help.

Comment: What is the encoding of the file? Could be BOM`s fault.

Comment: Which UI? What encoding do you want to use for the file? UTF-8? (CSV encoding is not standardized...)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at ContentEncoding under HttpResponse
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx
Whatever UI you're displaying the file in is probably using a different one to what's set there.

Answer (score -1):

I don't suppose you could simply check the file to see if it contains the character "Â".

Then if it does just replace it.

```
if (string.Contains("Â"))
        {
            string= string.Replace("Â", "");
        }
```

With string just being the contents of the file.

This is just a guess, I do not know if this would work.